# Writing numbers in file on new lines

Tags: python

I am trying to read one file `f1`, it contains numbers like this:

```
2
5
19
100
34
285
39
12
```

and I want to read this numbers, square them and write in a new file, each on new line. This is my code:

```
with open("Data.txt", 'r') as f1, open("Double.txt", 'w') as f2:
    Lines = f1.readlines()
    for new_line in Lines:
        if new_line.isdigit():
            x = int(new_line)
            x = pow(x, 2)
            on_new_line = str(x) + "\n"
            f2.write(on_new_line)
```

but in second file it writes only

```
144
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Note that each line you read will have newline (\n). So you need to rstrip ('\n'). And if the line has more than one number separated by space, then you need to split them using split(' ') or split(','). Can you share the data as it looks in your input file

Comment: Just a suggestion. You should put the code in the correct format, so it is valid python code.

Comment: it shows question like inline, i cant change it.

Comment: 2
5
19
100
34
285
39
12 its like that but not in row, each number is on new line like column

Comment: Now i see the code. After the for loop before the if statement, add `new_line = new_line.rstrip('\n')`. That should be enough. Otherwise your code looks ok

Comment: Your second `if` can be changed to: `if new_line.strip().isdigit():` and your code will work.  It's just the newline that is screwing up the `isdigit` function's result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the file is only returning 144 is because using `readlines()` returns the line as a string, which includes the newline character at the end: `\n`

We can solve this by reading the file in as a whole and splitting on the newline characters to put the items in an array:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f1, open('double.txt', 'w') as f2:
    lines = f1.read().split('\n')
    for new_line in lines:
        squared = int(new_line)**2
        f2.write(f"{squared}\n")
```

This will create an array with each item as a string, so on line 4, we cast that to an int in order to square it.

We also write each element to the new text file, with a newline character after it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate throw the file this way :

```
path1 = "Data.txt"
path2 = "Double.txt"

with open(path1, 'r') as f1, open(path2, 'w') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        try:
            f2.write(str(int(line)**2))
        except ValueError:
            pass
```